# Symfony child form listen to parent POST_SUBMIT

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to register an eventListener on a Symfony child form that get triggered after the parent form has been validated?
I assumed that POST_SUBMIT would do exactly this, but it looks like the child form is handled (submitted) before the parent gets validated. Partly explained here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18763

Is there another way to get the child to do something after the parent form has been validated?

Thanks, Hannes

Comment: Can you explain your use case and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a custom child form with a path to a previously uploaded file. After the parent form has been validated, I want to move that file into its final place. My other idea is to use entityListener (prePersist). But than I have to use an annotation reader to get all the properties that use my custom UploadedFileType (or another custom annotation).

Comment: The file has been previously uploaded through another API-Endpoint and lies in a tempfolder, my custom child formtype (UploadedFileType) take only a reference to that file. If the parent form in valid, the file needs to be move to its final place.

Comment: To me that's something that shouldn't happen in a form type (form types shouldn't have such side effects). This should rather be handled in your service layer (or in the controller processing the form).

Comment: Thanks @xabbuh. This is now handled in an entityListener, Hannes

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is interested. It looks like this is only possible with custom events. A good example can be found here: https://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2013/05/symfony2-defining-and-dispatching-custom-form-events/